Bitlocker encrypted USB drive cannot be opened via VirtualBox: Windows 11 on MacOS
As a way to gain access to a bitlocker encrypted usb drive, I decided to use Windows 11 via VM on my Mac OS 12.7.5. However, the encrypted USB file is not detected in VirtualBox, even after following these steps: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=82639#p390401.
A non-encrypted usb drive could be read in VirtualBox, so I think the installation of the VirtualBox extension package worked. However, the sole purpose of this VM is to gain access to the bitlocker encrypted usb drive. Does anybody have any recommendations?

While this may be borderline on-topic as VirtualBox on macOS is a key element of the setup, it may require a lot of WIndows expertise to answer. You may get better results asking in the VB forum you already link to.

This question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center.
